# How to locate files within my computer containing strings of text

Tags: file

### What I am trying to do:

I am trying to locate files with in the directory `\\xxxx` that contain strings of text `DSN=`, `Server=`, `UID=`, `Pwd=`, `Password=`.

The files do not have to contain every single string but at least two of them.

---

The files also have to be `.config`, `.asp` or `.inc`.

---

#### How could I go about locating these files? Do I need software, a certain coding language, etc..

---

## edit

Oh I forgot! And it should only go a maximum of two folders in from the root directory?

Comment: On what operation system?

Comment: You could use a program that uses regular expressions: http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I use a (free) search and replace tool called [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack).

Set both the file name and content to ***regular expression***.

And use:

- File name: `\.((config)|(asp)|(inc))$`
- Containing Text: `((DNS)|(Server)|(UID)|(Pwd)|(Password))=`

[image]

**========== Edit based on comments ==========**

Only 2 subfolders deep will certainly complicate things. The only potential solution I can give you without programming something yourself is to use the "Multiple Folders" search and add each one manually. Perhaps that's good enough for your situation.

[image]

Comment: @user2768038 Added a suggestion, hope that helps.

Comment: If you select one folder it searches all the folders within right? It doesn't just go to the files of the first folder?

Comment: @user2768038 Yes, you can see in the second screenshot that "Subfolders" is checked. You can enable/disable that as needed.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not see the images. But thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I have been fiddling with it for a while because it wasn't working as I had entered this: `\.((config)|(asp)|(inc))$ ` not this `\.((config)|(asp)|(inc))$`! Can you notice the difference?